# Restore document (not response of any document)

Tags: lotus-notes

For a reason I don't know a document has convert to be a response of another. I need to restore or free the document in order to this document not been a response document of any document.

I found a MakeResponse function but not find a function to undo it

Thank you

I tried to copy a documment to a new one, but the new copy is a reponse too.

Comment: Remove the $REF field and the document should be a normal document again

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten: That's the answer... I know it's short, but do you want to write a response from that? Don't want to take away your credit by just repeating your comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the $REF field and the document should be a normal document again.

Comment: Hello I get an error when try to change de value of $REF:  doc.$REF=""  it says "Unexpected $REF", Thank you

Comment: @Nikita - Setting a field's value doesn't remove the field. You need to completely remove it using the `RemoveItem` method.